# Can't align one column with DIVs with another DIV

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to have a colum with some DIVs on the left, and a big DIV on the right. I've started to try it on a fiddle and my first problem comes when I assign the border attribute to my DIVs.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="iframe"></div>
  <div id="tab1"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
 margin:0;
 background-color:yellow;
 height: 500px;
 width:100%;
}
#iframe{
 width: 85%;
 height: 100%;
 float: right;
 border: 1px solid red;
}
#tab1 {
 width: 15%;
 height: 15%;
 float:left;
 border: 1px solid green;  
}
```

[View on Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/galacticpower/wbq3ojfu/1/)

Anyway, I'm looking forward this goal (So maybe my approach is not the correct one...)

[image: project.png]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your border width is extending your elements width. Just add [`box-sizing: border-box;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to your elements to include your border into the given width. Then the floating should be as intended.

You can read more about the [CSS box model on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model) (thanks for the hint in the comments @tabs1200).

```
#iframe{
  ...
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#tab1 {
  ...
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Here is a working example:

```css
#container {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}
#iframe {
  width: 85%;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#tab1 {
  width: 15%;
  height: 15%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="iframe"></div>
  <div id="tab1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep - To understand why this solution works, read up on the [CSS box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model). It's pretty essential understanding for any web developer.

Answer (score 0):

Use box-sizing. This code should work:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```